# is there a way to run javascript inside CKeditor

Tags: php, javascript, html, content-management-system, ckeditor

I've been working on a CMS using php and just switched to `CKEditor`. I have an image `carousel/gallery` in a frontpage. Seeing the capability of `CKEditor`, I have decided to save its "html" in a database so that my client can edit it to change the images for the carousel or changing it to a new carousel type completely.

I've come to realize that `javascript` isn't running inside the `CKEditor` so I can't have a proper display of the `carousel`. It is looking rather messy due to the fact that javascript not running.

Is there any way around it? What are others options i have to let my client customize his carousel?

Thanks for reading this, and for helping out.

Comment: This is probably going to be way more complex than JS running in CKEditor (which it does. That is not the issue). The main problem will be that the `iframe` the editor  is in is not loading the required JS libraries. And I have an inkling that is only the first of your problems, because all the elements of the carousel would be editable as well.... I would drop it, and try to find a simpler solution.

Comment: The basic problem about "running javascript inside CKEditor" is that from that moment you can't be sure if the content of the editor is the real desired output, or it's just a temporary state set by javascript. Basic example: if you run 'document.write("Hello")' then the content will include that 'Hello', and when you run that script again in the page as the visitor loads the page, he will get the 'hello' saved from the content and a new one from running javascript at that moment. So, yes, it's possible to run javascript, but maybe that's not the correct solution for your problem.

Comment: any suggesting you can point me to? will be very much appreciated

Comment: build the carousel/gallery dynamically, for example by reading a directory's contents for the images or having a simple settings file for your customer to edit with image/url/text or whatever you need.

Comment: will consider that. thanks for everyone